# Dynamic pivot - how to obtain column titles parametrically?

Tags: t-sql

I wish to write a Query for SAP B1 (t-sql) that will list all Income and Expenses Items by total and month by month.

I have successfully written a Query using PIVOT, but I do not want the column headings to be hardcoded like: Jan-11, Feb-11, Mar-11 ... Dec-11.

Rather I want the column headings to be parametrically generated, so that if I input:

```
--------------------------------------
Query - Selection Criteria
--------------------------------------

Posting Date      greater or equal        01.09.10

Posting Date      smaller or equal        31.08.11

[OK]   [Cancel]
```

the Query will generate the following columns:

Sep-10, Oct-10, Nov-10, .....  Aug-11

I guess DYNAMIC PIVOT can do the trick.
So, I modified one SQL obtained from another forum to suit my purpose, but it does not work.  The error message I get is `Incorrect Syntax near 20100901`.

Could anybody help me locate my error?

Note: In SAP B1, '[%1]' is an input variable

Here's my query:

```
/*Section 1*/

DECLARE @listCol VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(4000)

-------------------------------------
/*Section 2*/

SELECT @listCol = 
STUFF(
   ( SELECT DISTINCT '],[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, MONTH(T0.RefDate), 102)
       FROM JDT1 
        FOR XML PATH(''))
     , 1, 2, '') + ']' 

------------------------------------
/*Section 3*/

SET @query = '
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT 
        T0.Account,
        T1.GroupMask,
        T1.AcctName,
        MONTH(T0.RefDate) as [Month],   
        (T0.Debit - T0.Credit) as [Amount]
    FROM dbo.JDT1 T0
   JOIN dbo.OACT T1 ON T0.Account = T1.AcctCode 
   WHERE
      T1.GroupMask IN (4,5,6,7) AND
      T0.[Refdate] >= '[%1]' AND
      T0.[Refdate] <= '[%2]'
 ) S
PIVOT 
(
    Sum(Amount)
    FOR [Month] IN ('+@listCol+')
) AS pvt
'

--------------------------------------------
/*Section 4*/

EXECUTE (@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know SAP, but a couple of things spring to mind:

- It looks like you want `@listCol` to contain a collection of numbers within square brackets, for example `[07],[08],[09]...`.  However, your code appears not to put a `[` at the start of this string.
- Try replacing the lines

  ```
  T0.[Refdate] >= '[%1]' AND
  T0.[Refdate] <= '[%2]'
  ```

  with

  ```
  T0.[Refdate] >= ''[%1]'' AND
  T0.[Refdate] <= ''[%2]''
  ```

(I also added a space before the `AND` in the first of these two lines while I was editing your question.)

Comment: Hi Luke, Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it does not solve my problem. I realize that the solutionn is going to be very difficult. Fortunately, I found this helpful article: http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx       I must now work hard to adapt these ideas to my problem.          Best Regards Leon Lai